# Uniform convergence implying convergence of generalized inverses

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be a sequence of non-decreasing functions converging uniformly to non-decreasing $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$.

Define $f^-:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f^-(p)= \inf\{x : f^-(x) \geq p\}$ and similarly for $f^-_n$.

Does $f_n^-$ converge pointwise to $f^-$? What if $f^-$ is continuous, does it hold then? How about uniform convergence?

## My attempt

I've only really thought about pointwise convergence.

We need to show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n \geq N$:

$$
\left| \inf\{x : f^-(x) \geq p\} - \inf\{x : f_n^-(x) \geq p\}\right| < \varepsilon .
$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and choose $N$ from the uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ so that for all $n \geq N$: $\sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \varepsilon$.

I was thinking that since $f(x) - \varepsilon < f_n(x) < f(x) + \varepsilon$ we could perhaps rewrite some of the infima but I can't really seem to make it add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least pointwise convergence isn't guaranteed. Let $f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}, && x < 1\\
1,&& x \geqslant 1
\end{cases}$. Then $f_n^-(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$, but $f^-(\frac{1}{2}) = 0$.

If $f^-$ is continuous then $f^-_n$ converges to $f^-$ at least pointwise. If $f^-$ is continuous then $f$ is strictly increasing (see proposition 2.3 from [a note on generalized inverses](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse.pdf) by Embrechts, Hofert). Let us take fix some $y \in [0, 1]$ and some $\varepsilon$ and prove $|f_n^-(y) - f^-(y)| < \varepsilon$ for significantly large $n$.

Let $x = f^-(y)$. Let $a = x - \varepsilon$, $b = x + \varepsilon$. Let $\delta$ be such that $f(a) + \delta < y < f(b) - \delta$ (such $\delta$ exists as $f$ is strictly increasing). Let $n_0$ be such that $\|f_n - f\| < \delta$ if $n > n_0$. Then if $n > n_0$, we have $f_n(a) < f(a) + \delta < y$ and $f_n(b) > f(b) - \delta > y$. So $a < f_n^-(y) < b$ and $|f_n^-(y) - f^-(y)| = |f_n^-(y) - x| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Theres no need for $\varepsilon/2$ is there? Doesn't the argument work with setting $a= x-\varepsilon$ and $b$ similarly?

Comment: Indeed, there isn't. I first thought that we will need it because $f_n$ approximates $f$ not exactly, but it appeared it doesn't matter there.